# How does nodejs understand/read c++ code?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I clearly understand Javascript only. I am curious about how Node.js understand C++ code as they are completely different things. How do they communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using language bindings.

The JS interpreter is able to import and call into exported linker symbols from a library, and with language bindings you can provide these, e.g by writing some functionality in C++.

Comment: Does it involve compilers?

Comment: Yes. Here is a Hello World, you can have a look: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#hello-world